# Deform bone will not follow IK bone perfectly with copy rotation

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to separate bone layers with ik fk central and deform layers.  I am having problem with copy rotation from IK>central>def bones (each in different layers.)  The deform bone will not follow the IK bone perfectly.  Or follow but with lag time.  I have redo the rig 2 times already.  I am not sure what is wrong and I do not know how to debug.

Please I really need help.

What can I do to fix this?
sharing file not blender exchange:
[image]

Thank you.
please see the sample pic.
[image]

Comment: your armature seems complicated, could you please explain more in details, with screenshots?

Comment: I am having 4 layers for arms.  FK, IK, central & deform layer.  central layer copies actions from FK and IK.  The deform layer "only" copies actions from central layer.  As such, I hope to only have IK/FK switch on central layer.  My problem is that when IK is on, the deform lower arm(elbow) would dislocate or will not move insyn with the central lower arm or IK lower arm.

Comment: so what you call layers are your bones? Sorry your armature is too complicated for me and I'm a bit lost, maybe you have your reasons but I'm not sure why you don't use a simpler one, anyway I hope someone will understand and help

Comment: I mean, I put FK, IK, central and deform bones in different layers as to manage them.  The issue I am having is that my right arm bones are working fine, but left would not.  Can you give me a pointer on debugging tho?

Comment: When I test your armature I don't see any problem, maybe if the right bones work just symmetrize, it won't help to understand why it didn't work on the left but at least it will fix it  ;)  other than that, I'm not sure why you talk about layers, in what way is it important? Also, why is your armature so complicated, does it allow you to do things a simpler one could not do, and if so, what?

Comment: hmm..I dont know if its complicated or not.  I just want the arm twist as the result of turning hand (y-axis wise) and ability to turn FK IK on/off.

Comment: what about coming back to a simpler solution: IK controller parented to root bone, hand parented to controller, only one bone for upper arm, one for lower arm, lower arm is IK with a chain length of 2, controller is its target, also create a pole target. If you want the lower arm to rotate give it a copy rotation above the IK... it should work the way you want or I miss something...

Comment: Yeah~ testing new rig.  I wanted to minimize # of bones and faster posing.  oh.. and I thought I had IK parented to the root bone...

Comment: ok, if you get stuck somewhere please tell me and I'll make a full answer, then maybe you'll tell in what way it doesn't fit your need

Comment: it's the IK controller bone (or "target" bone) that needs to be parented to the root bone, not the IK bone (lower arm)   ;)

Comment: I am not sure how to handle this.  How can I add IK to figure tip bone so that it will not create dependency cycle?  I want the figures to be able to target on a spot while moving the whole arm.  Every time I add IK to figure tips, i get dependency cycle.

Comment: do you mean fingertip? For finger I create copy rotation for the second and third phalange so that you just need to rotate the first one and the other ones follow. The first one is parented to the hand bone which is parented to the IK controller bone.